# Using PHP to replace XHTML tags and add parameters via preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Suppose you have the following code (such portions specified by `<art></art>` with a unique ID are multiple):

```
<art id="001">
<p class="prim"><h1>word1</h1>Text</p>
</art>

<art id="002">
<p class="prim"><h1>word2</h1>Text</p>
<p class="sec"><h1>word2.1</h1>Text</p>
</art>
```

How can I then use PHP, presumably the function `preg_replace` to find and replace each of the unique portions delimited by `<art></art>` (let us call this an article)? The output should be as follows:

```
<tra id="001" title="word1">
<index value="word1">
<p class="prim"><h1>word1</h1>Text</p>
</tra>

<tra id="002" title="word2">
<index value="word2" />
<p class="prim"><h1>word2</h1>Text</p>
<p class="sec"><h1>word2.1</h1>Text</p>
</tra>
```

Currently, I am struggling with using the regular expressions to go over a line break and limiting it to modify each article individually. What it does is that it takes the first `<art>` and the last `</art>` and replaces everything in between by the contents of a single article. The code I am using is as follows (everything is stored into the variable `$text`; the `s` modifier is to include line breaks):

```
$text = preg_replace("#\<art id=\"(.+)\"\>(.+)\<p class=\"prim\"\>\<h1\>(.+?)\</h1\>#s", '<tra id="$1" title="$3"><index value="$3" /><p class="main"><h2>$3</h2>', $text);
$text = preg_replace("#\</art#", '</tra', $text);
```

Another basic explanation of my goal is to take everything delimited by `<art></art>` individually, store specific portions into local variables and then completely rebuild it using those variables and additional text. I can do this with specific lines, but then I am unable to pass the content of the variable storing e.g. `word1` a line above to modify to `<art id="001" title="word1">`.

I have spent hours searching for a solution but I seem to be making an elementary mistake (regex beginner). Help me, please.

Comment: Does it need to be done with a regexp? This kind of task tends to be easier with any of the builtin DOM libraries.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Absolutely. I have never done such task before so I have chosen the first approach that I found.

Comment: You might want to read [Why you shouldn't parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/459233) - and because in programming in general everything is debatable, you might want to also read another opinion: [Oh Yes You Can Use Regexes to Parse HTML!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/459233). If I were you, I'd go for [DOM Manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Alright. Whatever, I've posted a non-regexp answer. It hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thank you, it is an interesting reading material.

Comment: Can you please point out why none of the 5000+ questions asking how to parse HTML/XML could answer your question? You are supposed to do research before asking.

Comment: @Gordon I have done the research and tried many variants but without success. I have little experience with PHP so what you can see as obvious, I see as a huge mess (e.g. at first I did not know that I can exchange delimiters and hence some of the regex strings I have found seemed a bit different and so on). There obviously are people willing to help so after at least three hours of reading various documentation, I had the nerve to post a question.

Comment: I didnt say it was obvious. I asked you to point out why none of the existing answers could solve your problem. As for "people willing to help": yes, sure. There will always be some people providing answers when they really shouldnt. The thing is, none of what you have been given for answers is particularly new. It's the same old code and links that we give to people asking how to [parse HTML three times a day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little starting point. It's probably not the simplest way and it doesn't fully comply with your specs but I hope it can give you some ideas to start coding:

```
<?php

$fragment = '<art id="001">
<p class="prim"><h1>word1</h1>Text</p>
</art>

<art id="002">
<p class="prim"><h1>word2</h1>Text</p>
<p class="sec"><h1>word2.1</h1>Text</p>
</art>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTML($fragment);
libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);

$articles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('art');
foreach($articles as $article){
    $titles = $article->getElementsByTagName('h1');
    if($titles->length>0){
        $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $index = $dom->createElement('index');
        $index->setAttribute('value', $title);

        $article->appendChild($index);
    }
}

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

... will print this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<art id="001"><p class="prim"></p>
<h1>word1</h1>Text
<index value="word1"></index></art><art id="002"><p class="prim"></p>
<h1>word2</h1>Text
<p class="sec"></p>
<h1>word2.1</h1>Text
<index value="word2"></index></art>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is indeed helpful because my knowledge of this DOM is null so a demonstration comes handy.

Comment: One more thing: Could you please tell me how to support utf-8? Latin characters, for example, are returned e.g. as Å¡ÄÄ¾Å¡Å¥Å¾Ã½Ä.

Comment: Wide question. Try second argument in [constructor](http://es.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php) to begin with.